# How to determine that the user is not on predefine route in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an application based on location and map. I have a predefine route on map from location A to location B. Now i want to determine if any user navigates far from predefine route. How can we determine that the user is far away from predefine route. I tried a lot to find out any such API which is helpful but couldn't. Hope i will find some solution here.

Comment: How woud you determine that a user is on a predefined route?

Comment: @greenapps. That is my question. i want to track the user if he navigates far from predefine route.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath` method from the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).